# scikit learn transform multiple text features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to classify multiple text features to a status. The data includes messages (errors and warnings) from different servers with the components and will result in different states. For example:

```
ServerName     Name     Description                               Severity   State
-------------- -------- ----------------------------------------- ---------- -------------
QWERT-XY-123   MySQL    Service not available on target machine   error      important
QWERT-XY-146   Oracle   Service caused an error                   warning    unimportant
...
```

This is a part of the vectorizing:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer

vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()

X_Servername = df["ServerName"].values
X_Name = df["Name"].values
X_Description = df["Description"].values
X_Severity = df["Severity"].values
y = df["State"].values

X_Servername = vectorizer.transform(X_Servername)
X_Name = vectorizer.transform(X_Name)
X_Description = vectorizer.transform(X_Description)

features=list(zip(X_Servername,X_Name,X_Description,X_Severity))
```

Now I want to fit the Model:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC(kernel = "linear", probability=True)
model.fit(features, y)
```

And the result is the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-71455dd49f0b> in <module>()
  2 
  3 model = SVC(kernel = "linear", probability=True)
----> 4 model.fit(features, y)
  5 
  6 #print(model.score(X_test, y))

D:\Enviroment\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
147         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
148 
149 -->     X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
151 

D:\Enviroment\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
573 -->                 ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
574     if multi_output:
575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

D:\Enviroment\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
431                                       force_all_finite)
432     else:
433 -->     array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
434 
435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So my question is about how to use multiple features with the hashingvectorizer or is the only way putting all features into one line?

Thanks for your help.

### Update

The failer is on how to build the vectorized feature list. Instead of:

```
features=list(zip(X_Servername,X_Name,X_Description,X_Severity))
```

I now uses this function where `extracted` appends all created vectorized values (X_ServerName, X_Name, ...):

```
def combine(extracted):
    if any(sparse.issparse(fea) for fea in extracted):
        stacked = sparse.hstack(extracted).tocsr()
        stacked = stacked.toarray()
    else:
        stacked = np.hstack(extracted)

    return stacked
```

Comment: You never `fit` your vectorizer before you attempt to transform your data. I'm guessing your output isn't what you think it is before you try to fit the SVC

Comment: Hi @G.Anderson thanks for your reply.
I `fit` the vectorizer with `fit_transform` but there is still the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. while using SVM in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485503/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-while-using-svm-in-scikit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, gen_features
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

cat_features = ["ServerName", "Name", "Description", "Severity"]
gf = gen_features(cat_features, [HashingVectorizer])
mapper = DataFrameMapper(gf)
cat_features_transformed = mapper.fit_transform(df)

target_name_encoded = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df["State"])

from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC(kernel = "linear", probability=True)
model.fit(cat_features_transformed, target_name_encoded)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='linear', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

### For test/prediction part ###

test_features_transformed = mapper.transform(df_test)
predictions = model.predict(test_features_transformed)
```

Note, you may need to run

```
pip install sklearn-pandas
```

if you do not have `sklearn-pandas` installed on your machine.

The aforementioned solution will allow you (1) transform your data to suitable format and later (2) apply the same fitted transformations to your test data via `transform` method.

Please let us know if this helps

Comment: Is there an advantage of using sklearn-pandas to building a solution based on column transformer or feature union and incorporating these into a pipeline?

Comment: Seems to solve my problem. The model can be `fit`. I will test it tomorrow :-)

Comment: @KRKirov `DataFrameMapper` and `ColumnTransformer` are basically the same, the code of using `gen_features` is knitter. But you always can achieve the same by writing the sequence of transformations explicitly.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, thanks for the response. Pardon me for saying this, but I find the solution based on sklearn-pandas somewhat untidy. It would have probably been easier to read a solution based on a pipeline using the standard sklearn transformers.