# convert sequence to array element

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to input data into a random-forest classifier, but it keeps telling me I'm using a sequence. I'm not sure how to convert the sequence into anything that is acceptable

I have tried feeding it into the classifier inside a `list()`, but that didn't work either.

this is an example of X_train[1]:

```
array([30, array([[0, 0, 1]]), 5.2304265, 7.233890799999999,
       array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]), 0, 0, 0,
       2, 10000.0, 13000.0, 30, 1], dtype=object)
```

.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

...produces...
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I expected it to accept the data, since it it is numerical, but it appears to reject the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. while using SVM in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485503/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-while-using-svm-in-scikit)

Comment: Googling your error along with "RandomForestClassifier" or "scikit-learn" gives the answer.

Comment: Your data is a mix of numbers and arrays.  And the arrays vary in shape.  An array is a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit) for the `fit()` method from sci-kit learn.

It clearly states that the training features `X` must be of the following format

```py
X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
```

It is expecting a 2D array. You will have to modify your training data to match the required format.